# what software has been used to write annotations on this pdf?

Tags: pdf, evince, okular, annotation

Here it is the screenshot, clicking on the ballot there appears the annotation. I already tried okular but I'm not able to reach the same result (actually to save annotation I have to export the pdf as Document Archive, which makes it unreadable for every other pdf reader)

[image]

I opened it with Document Viewer

Comment: You can print the pdf you annotated with Okular to a new pdf file.

Comment: @DKBose I already looked at metadata, nothing useful

//
    UTF-8 sure, but I would lose the annotations, I don't get what you mean